# Difference between "a" and "the"?

Tags: articles

I have a question regarding the usage of articles. 
What is the difference between "a" and "the"?

Why do I need to use "a" in "that was a winter I"ll never forget."? Can I use "the" instead?

Also, why do I need to use "the" in "that was the winter we went to Norway"?

Thank you very much!!^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The* is used to refer to specific or particular nouns; *a* is used to modify non-specific or non-particular nouns.

*the* = definite article

*a* = indefinite article

For example, if I say, "*Let's read the book,*" I mean a specific book. If I say, "*Let's read a book,*" I mean any book rather than a specific book.

Another example, "I went to *a* forest. *The *forest* was big.". In this first forest was indefinite one, and after I said the first sentence it became definite one and used *the* instead.

And in your example, winter is indefinite on "that was a winter I"ll never forget." and become definite and used *the* in "that was the winter we went to Norway".

[Reference](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it very clearly and now I know the difference between these two articles. Thanks again!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

The second of two coreferential noun phrases must be definite.  The first (indefinite) noun phrase may be inexplicit in a conversational context, so that the use of "the" conveys to a hearer the assumption that there is such a unique thing in the context which could have been mentioned, even if that was not done explicitly.

For instance, if I am talking to you on the phone and I say "I've got one here on the bed," now you know there is a bed in my vicinity, and only one nearby bed that the thing could be on. It would be tiresome if we had to make all such background assumptions explicit.